# Buffer API authentication with Python

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm trying to authorise the API for Buffer (the social media scheduling app). I'm following the instructions here https://buffer.com/developers/api/oauth

The first step of the authorisation, redirects the user to an authorisation page using a request of the type:

```
GET https://bufferapp.com/oauth2/authorize?
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=...&
    response_type=code
```

Once authorise the page redirects to the redirect_uri with the authorisation code as a query parameter:

```
http://example.com/back?code=1/mWot20jTwojsd00jFlaaR45
```

That code is then to be used in a POST request to obtain an access token:

```
POST https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json

POST Data
     client_id=...&
     client_secret=...&
     redirect_uri=...&
     code=...&
     grant_type=authorization_code
```

However, the authorisation code has a 30sec valid life.

When I do the authorisation **manually** and then a POST request with the auth_code I receive like so:

```
my_data = {
    'client_id': my_client_id,
    'client_secret': my_client_secret,
    'redirect_uri': my_redirect_uri,
    'code': auth_code,
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
}

token = requests.post('https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json', data=my_data)
```

I get an "invalid grant" error.

I looked up the error in relation to other APIs (Buffer API doesn't seem to be used that much) and one cause for it might be an expired auth_code. Which wouldn't be surprising given the short shelf life.

What's a good way to automate the authorisation bit to avoid expiration of the auth_code?

Or is it something else I'm doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

> Buffer is an OAuth 2.0 provider.

You have to use a OAuth 2 Workflow, read about

Requests-OAuthlib: [OAuth 2 Workflow](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html)

> The following sections provide some example code that demonstrates some of the possible OAuth2 flows you can use with requests-oauthlib. We provide four examples: one for each of the grant types defined by the OAuth2 RFC. These grant types (or workflows) are the Authorization Code Grant (or Web Application Flow), the Implicit Grant (or Mobile Application Flow), the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant (or, more succinctly, the Legacy Application Flow), and the Client Credentials Grant (or Backend Application Flow).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this out